# Node JS dont use SendGrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Error: The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements
at Request._callback (C:\Users\aslan\Desktop\Node-Express — копия\node_modules\sendgrid\lib\sendgrid.js:88:25)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\aslan\Desktop\Node-Express — копия\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:375:28)
at Request. (C:\Users\aslan\Desktop\Node-Express — копия\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:375:28)
at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\aslan\Desktop\Node-Express — копия\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

follow these screen shots and then add add sender that email you using in from attribute of send grid config, you will receive an email verify that and you will see your self approved as sender of send-grid